# Custom annotation not being detected by Spring AOP

Tags: java, spring, annotations, aop

So, I've been trying to play with Spring AOP, but as soon as I start using custom method annotations, the AOP stops working.

Here is the annotation:

```
package com.test.annotations;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface Performance {

}
```

The Aspect:

```
package com.test.aspects;

import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;


@Component
@Aspect
public class Audience {
    @Pointcut("@annotation(com.test.annotations.Performance)")
    public void performance() {
    }

    @Around("performance()")
    public void beforePerformance(ProceedingJoinPoint jointPoint) throws Throwable{
        System.out.println("The audience is getting ready for the show");

        jointPoint.proceed();

        System.out.println("The show is over, audience's leaving");
    }

}
```

The class using custom annotations:

```
package com.test.performers;

import com.test.annotations.Performance;
import com.test.exceptions.PerformanceException;

public interface Performer {
    @Performance
    void perform() throws PerformanceException;
}
```

Finally, the relevant part of the main method.

```
Performer kenny = (Performer) context.getBean("guitarist");
kenny.perform();
```

The Guitarist class is implementing the performer interface.

I've been looking around for a few hours, I can't see what I'm doing wrong. Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no inheritance in annotations. In `Guitaritst` class, when overriding the `perform()` method, you should annotate it as well.